# MAX numeric value from mixed array

Tags: php

I have an array that contains both strings and numeric values, While using this code I keep getting the highest string value, how to get only numeric max values from the array?

```
$maxprice = max($textpieces);
```

I have also tried this but this just returns the number of keys in the array

```
 $maxprice = max(array_search($textpieces));
```

thanks for your help! I have looked but the max function here does not give any information http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

I have also looked at this solution [Find highest max() of mixed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445030/find-highest-max-of-mixed-array) but is it possible to get it without building an custom function?

Answer (score 4):

```
$maxprice = max(array_filter($textpieces, 'is_numeric'));
```

It at first filters only entries that contains digits only (integers) and then extracts `max()` from it

The following solution:

```
$max = array_reduce($textpieces, function($max, $i) {
    if (is_numeric($i) && $i > $max) {
        return $i;
    }

    return $max;
});

var_dump($max);
```

could be a bit more performance (from both CPU and memory perspectives) but is more complicated as well.

Comment: probably better than the uksort() method was going to suggest

Comment: This will not work as expected. `ctype_digit` expects a string to be passed to it. If the value is integer type, it will attempt to look for the ascii char value of that integer. If it happens to be the ascii value for a digit it will return true; otherwise it will return false.

Comment: @Crayon Violent: can you demonstrate that?

Comment: `look at example #2 of the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Comment: @Crayon Violent: nice, didn't know that. Second attempt then )